# Finding Sentinel tile for specific Long/Lat coordinate

Tags: remote-sensing, latitude-longitude, sentinel-2, mgrs, amazon-web-services

I'm building a tool that downloads images from "Sentinel-2 on AWS"

I have a trouble translating Long/Lat coordinates to a specific Sentinel tile. I know that Sentinel 2 uses MGRS and I tried to simply convert Long/Lat to MGRS and with low precision I get the S2A tile ID. And it works, but not always.

For example, Long/Lat 34.665,31.625 resolves to "36R XA" in MGRS, but the Sentinel tile 36RXA doesn't exist.

What would be the right way of determining Sentinel tile using Long/Lat coordinates?

Comment: Intersect with the [Sentinel-2 tiling grid](https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/1955685/S2A_OPER_GIP_TILPAR_MPC__20151209T095117_V20150622T000000_21000101T000000_B00.kml)?

Comment: Yeah, I saw this KML. That would be my last resort since lookups are expensive. I hope I can do it with calculation

Comment: Check out https://github.com/sat-utils/sentinel2-util

Comment: You can do this in Google Cloud as they have all the meta data in BigQuery, eg, `SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index] where north_lat < 50 and north_lat > 49 order by sensing_time LIMIT 10`, but you mention AWS, so I guess this won't help.

Answer (score 7):

> ⚠️ Sentinelsat is currently not functional for downloading from the
> CDSE
>
> Sentinelsat can still be used against [other data
> hubs](https://github.com/kr-stn/awesome-sentinel#data-hubs-and-national-mirrors)
> powered by the [DHuS software](https://github.com/SentinelDataHub/).

Such a tool already exists. It is called Sentinelsat and the [source is available on GitHub](https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat). It offers a command line interface and a Python API. It works with Sentinel 1 and 2. The spatial query is based on a polygon and not a point, but otherwise this is exactly what you need.

EDIT:

1. you can return the product ID (or product ID list) using the query function. And from the command line, you can omit the -d option in order not to launch the download (and use the `-f` option to create the footprint of each image)
2. Concerning the GeoJSON, you can see below that a WKT could be used directly instead. As mentioned by @ThingumaBob, you can create a tiny polygon based on your lat/long coordinates. But in fact, I've tested it with a point GeoJSON, and it also worked fine. So there is no need to convert your point into polygon.

```py
# search by polygon, time, and Hub query keywords
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('map.geojson'))
products = api.query(footprint,
                     date = ('20151219', date(2015, 12, 29)),
                     platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
                     cloudcoverpercentage = (0, 30))
```

which could be adjusted into

```py
# search by point, time, and Hub query keywords

products = api.query('POINT({0} {1})'.format(longitude,latitude),
                     date = ('20151219', date(2015, 12, 29)),
                     platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
                     cloudcoverpercentage = (0, 30))
```

Comment: thanks @radouxju, I am aware of Sentinelsat, but my specific need is to get the tile name for a corresponding lat/lon. I do not know if Sentinelsat does that

Comment: @user1186 produce a *tiny* bbox around the lat/lon to feed the API? seems silly but could be all you need...

Comment: @ThingumaBob, I could do that but the API will return NDVI values. I only want the tile ID, if there is a way to do that through the API, I would love to know

Answer (score 6):

S2 partitioning in MGRS is tricky specially when the data is between UTM zones and the tiles overlap, see the figure below. Tiles from left to right are 20_M_QE, 20_M_RE, 21_M_SV and 21_M_TV:

A search made through opensearch for the region returns one S2 acquisition broken in two tiles, 20_M_RE and 21_M_TV:

[image: 20_M_RE]

[image]

So if you are interested in data in the represented 21_M_SV tile region you should use 20_M_RE. Note that the representation used in the examples (shapefile obtained from NGA) the overlap between tiles is not represented.

The safest way to obtain the tiles seems to be search your AOI using opensearch and then retrieving the returned tiles, or using the sentinel2-util tool as mentioned by bugmenot123.

If you choose to map the Long/Lat to tiles I recommend using the KML provided by ESA as the tiling grid definition:

https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I use for doing this with coordinates from shapefiles, using Sentinelsat package as well:

```py
## Identify tile
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import box
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI

# import the data
polygons = gpd.read_file(shapefile)

# transform CRS
polygons = polygons.to_crs("EPSG:4326")

# bound box
bounds = polygons.total_bounds
bound_box = box(*bounds)

# query scenes
api = SentinelAPI('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')

footprint = bound_box

product = api.query(footprint, 
                    date=('NOW-14DAYS', 'NOW'), 
                    platformname='Sentinel-2', 
                    producttype= 'S2MSI1C', 
                    area_relation='Contains',
                    limit=1
                    )

# get tile
for value in product.values():
    tile = value['tileid']
```

Based on radouxju answer I think this may work for what you want [Edit: fixed bug in lon,lat ordering]:

```py
## Identify tile by Long/Lat
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI

# coordinates
lat = 31.625
lon = 34.665

# query scenes
api = SentinelAPI('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')

footprint = 'POINT(%s %s)' % (lon, lat)

product = api.query(footprint, 
                    date=('NOW-14DAYS', 'NOW'), 
                    platformname='Sentinel-2', 
                    producttype= 'S2MSI1C', 
                    area_relation='Contains',
                    limit=1
                    )

# get tile
for value in product.values():
    tile = value['tileid']
```