# Sentinel 3 OLCI/SLSTR granule footprints shapefile?

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-3

Basically the following question:
[Finding Sentinel tile for specific Long/Lat coordinate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227847/finding-sentinel-tile-for-specific-long-lat-coordinate)

However, that question was regarding Sentinel 2 MSI, for which a UTM tiling grid is made available by the ESA.

For a given study area, I would like to find out which Sentinel 3 OLCI (and possibly SLSTR) granules are needed. Is anyone aware of a file describing the footprints of these granules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the search on the [Sentinel-3 Pre-Operations Data Hub](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/s3):

[image: Find Sentinel3 Granules by Location]

---

Of course you can use [the API](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/5APIsAndBatchScripting) and/or [OpenSeach](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/5APIsAndBatchScripting#Using_Open_Search_to_discover_pr) to automate that.

e.g.

> [https://scihub.copernicus.eu/s3/search?q=footprint:"Intersects(41.9000,12.5000)"](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/s3/search?q=footprint:%22Intersects(41.9000,12.5000)%22)
>   user/pw=s3guest

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of this functionality. Quite frankly, it was the reason why I was posting here. Is there not a more systematic approach for this? I would like to be able to automatically find the right granules for any given geometry.

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to the API and an example.

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick. I still might contact the ESA with the question to release a shapefile because that saves a lot of queries.

Comment: I doubt that will be possible as they are not as regular as Sentinel 2.